# Cypher query: finding path with alternating relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have following graph

```
(1)-[A]->(2)-[B]->(3)-[A]->(4)-[B]->(5)-[A]->(6)-[B]->(7)-[A]->(8)
```

How do i specify a Cypher query that finds a path between (1) and (8) such that they are connected by alternating a and b relationships?

I have a playable version here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=84b3mz

A query like this gives me the path, however i need to start specifying conditions on the collection p

```
START s=node(1) 
MATCH p=s-[r*]->e 
WHERE e.name="8" 
RETURN p
```

A better way would be something like

```
MATCH p=s-([:A]->()-[:B])*->e
```

is something like that possible in Cypher?

Comment: Share what you have tried please.

Comment: Okay, i added some code and a link to rabbithole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you can do `[r:A|B*]`, but that doesn't enforce that they must alternate. If you must enforce that, you can do it in an ALL:

```
MATCH p=(s)-[:A|B*]->(e) 
WHERE s.name="1" 
WITH p, range(0,length(p)-1) AS idx // create a list of indexes to go through
WHERE ALL (i IN idx 
  WHERE CASE i % 2 = 0  
          WHEN TRUE THEN type(rels(p)[i])= "A" // even indexes are "A"
          ELSE type(rels(p)[i])= "B" // odd indexes are "B"
        END ) 
RETURN p,idx
```

The caveat here is that this isn't going to be super performant if you end up with a lot of paths from the first match. It's going to have to scan through all of them, verifying that they are in the right order.

Comment: a more elegant way would probably be to create a new relation "AB" from e.g. (1) to (3) and then navigate via these new links, yes?

Comment: That is an option, but I don't consider changing the database a valid way to make a query work. You'd have to orchestrate the updates when things are changed, to keep those new links up to date.

Comment: I have a problem running the queue - "Argument to all is not a predicate"

Comment: It works in the console example you sent. What version of Neo are you using?

Comment: It sounds like maybe CASE had some issues with types in M06.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44071/discussion-between-stasik-and-wes-freeman)